# "Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported" getting this issue on android 11 and above device

Tags: javascript, android

I am getting this issue on android 11 and above device, I am using Google Maps JavaScript APi, how to resolve this issue.

"Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params#required_parameters"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params#required_parameters%22), source: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&key